# How to enable mat-table with multi selection and dynamic columns

Tags: angular-material

I am trying to enable multi selection options with dynamic columns. Though dynamic columns are working multi selection is not working.

Regards

jcm

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort="matSort">
        <ng-container [matColumnDef]="col.columnDef" *ngFor=" let col of displayColumns">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
                {{ col.header }}
                <ng-container [matColumnDef]="select">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                        <mat-checkbox #checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null" [disabled]="isDisabled" [checked]="selectionTable.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                            [indeterminate]="selectionTable.hasValue() &&
                                                                              !isAllSelected()"></mat-checkbox>
                    </th>
                </ng-container>
            </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element ">{{ element[col.columnDef] }}</td>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="$event ? selectionTable.toggle(row) : null" [checked]="selectionTable.isSelected(row)"></mat-checkbox>
            </td>
        </ng-container>
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnDefs"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnDefs; "></tr>
    </mat-table>
```

Comment: This is what you want? -> https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#selection

Comment: Well, I have already checked this out and is what I have already done, but the problem is that I am unable to make it work (ie, multi selection with checkbox) when the columns are dynamically added. :(

Comment: Can you provide StackBlitz?

Comment: It would be better if you are ready to explain a bit more about - *when the columns are dynamically added*

Comment: OK. What I am aiming to achieve is to have a generic mat-table component, where the columns to be rendered will be supplied from different components, only the logic of adding the columns will be present in this component. which is working, but not working in combination with multi selection checkbox.

Comment: Do the table have the same action's, operation?

Comment: For example: Employee List and Student List are rendered in a generic table then how you are going to handle two method's if they have like: `getEmployeeDetails()` and `getStudentDetails()`?

Comment: Where is the code of `*which is working, but not working in combination with multi selection checkbox*`?

Comment: This mat-table component is a child component of StudentList and EmployeeList components. using @ViewChild, the "displayColumns" and "columnDefs" are set. StudentList and EmployeeList implement a common interface say...ListBase.  I am trying to create a stackblitz...need some time. I have pasted the code snippet above.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a header to `displayColumns` for the multi-select column, and when you running over them using `*ngFor`, you have to check using `*ngIf` whether you are in the first header (which belongs to the multi-select column) or in the other headers (which belongs to the dynamic columns), and create the header and column respectively.

You can see an example I made in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multiselect-with-dynamic-columns).

Comment: this is a fantastic example, but I'm having one issue that I can't seem to figure out. The column headers are being populated by the corresponding key:value pairs. How can I choose the column headers? I have been trying to figure this out all day- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57812228/cdk-angular-table-with-dynamic-checkboxes-not-finding-correct-column-names

Comment: @RyanIndustries8 what do you mean? do you want to set the name of the headers yourself and not use Object.keys? If yes, I don't know how you can achieve dynamic table otherwise.

If you wish to edit the name of the key (for example if the key is "firstName" and you want to make the header "First Name"), I would add a pipe to mat-header-cell that does it.

Comment: I've edited my stackblitz example to your requirements, and also answered your question, hope it will help you!

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you, I didn't even think about splicing the key. I appreciate you taking the time to do this :)